# How can I know whether a Java object is in tenure or eden space from heap dump

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot, heap-dump

I have a Hotspot JVM heap dump and I tried to find out whether an object is live in tenure space, eden space, or survivor space, but I could not.

Appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that you need to know this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can.  From [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/3456/) forum post,

> sorry, bad news, the heap dump neither contains the info about the
>   space  the object is in

Looking at the contents of the java heap dumps from this [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tooldescr-136044.html#gbltw) seems to confirm that the heap dump does not contain generation info,

```
HEAP DUMP BEGIN (39793 objects, 2628264 bytes) Wed Oct 4 13:54:03 2006
ROOT 50000114 (kind=<thread>, id=200002, trace=300000)
ROOT 50000006 (kind=<JNI global ref>, id=8, trace=300000)
ROOT 50008c6f (kind=<Java stack>, thread=200000, frame=5)
:
CLS 50000006 (name=java.lang.annotation.Annotation, trace=300000)
    loader        90000001
OBJ 50000114 (sz=96, trace=300001, class=java.lang.Thread@50000106)
    name        50000116
    group        50008c6c
    contextClassLoader    50008c53
    inheritedAccessControlContext    50008c79
    blockerLock    50000115
OBJ 50008c6c (sz=48, trace=300000, class=java.lang.ThreadGroup@50000068)
    name        50008c7d
    threads    50008c7c
    groups        50008c7b
ARR 50008c6f (sz=16, trace=300000, nelems=1, 
     elem type=java.lang.String[]@5000008e)
    [0]        500007a5
CLS 5000008e (name=java.lang.String[], trace=300000)
    super        50000012
    loader        90000001
```

Comment: +1: If you take a `jmap -dump:live` you can be sure nothing is in the eden space as it performs a GC to determine which objects are live.

Comment: Can you at least tell apart PermGen from the rest?

Comment: @PeterLawrey will that sweep the tenured space too? Thx!